# ambigous string date to datetime/date C#

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

If there's string date like '9/10/2002', how can I define whether the date is 9 October 2002 or 10 September 2002 in c#?

How to store it in date/datetime variable?

Comment: The data format is depending on your system setup, for windows, check your Date & time setting for  the format.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell what the author intended when they wrote it, unless you told them what you expected, or have some other dates that you could use to spot values greater than 12.

However, when you know the format, you can use something like this to ensure it is parsed in the required format:

```
string myDate = "9/10/2001";
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
DateTime.TryParseExact(myDate, pattern, enUS,  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out datelimit);
```

This is a good reason to use a datepicker in your user interface.

Comment: i see... i just want to make sure is there any way for me to do that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to identify from the string date whether its using dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy format. That will need to be figured out, then to store that in the date time variable

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(2002, 9, 10);
```

Please refer https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format for further reference.

Comment: Sometimes it can be inferred - 12/25/2020 is quite unambiguous. And from that you could infer it for a set of dates as soon as 1 date has a day > 12.